# How to calculate a One-Hot Encoding value into a real-valued vector?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

In Word2Vec, i've learned that both of CBOW and Skip-gram produce a one-hot encoding value to create a vector (cmiiw), I wonder how to calculate or represents a One-Hot Encoding value into a real-valued vector, for example (source: [DistrictDataLab's Blog about Distributed Representations](http://blog.districtdatalabs.com/nlp-research-lab-part-1-distributed-representations))
from this:
[image: One-Hot Encoding's example]
into:
[image: One-Hot Encoding's example]
please help, I was struggling on finding this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word2vec algorithm itself is what incrementally learns the real-valued vector, with varied dimension values.

In contrast to the one-hot encoding, these vectors are often called "dense embeddings". They're "dense" because unlike the one-hot encoding, which is "sparse" with many dimensions and mostly zero values, they have fewer dimensions and (usually) no zero-values. They're an "embedding" because they've "embed" a discrete set-of-words into another continuous-coordinate-system.

You'd want to read the [original word2vec paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781) for a full formal description of how the dense embeddings are made.

But the gist is that the dense vectors start totally random, and so at first the algorithm's internal neural network is useless for predicting neighboring words. But each (context)->(target) word training example from a text corpus is tried against the network, and each time the difference from the desired prediction is used to apply a tiny nudge, towards a better prediction, to both word-vector and internal-network-weight values.

Repeated many times, initially with larger nudges (higher learning-rate) then with ever-smaller nudges, the dense vectors rearrange their coordinates from their initial randomness to a useful relative-arrangement – one that's about-as-good as possible for predicting the training text, given the limits of the model itself. (That is, any further nudge that improves predictions on some examples, worsens it on others – so you might as well consider training done.)

You then read the resulting dense embedding real-valued vectors out of the model, and use them for purposes other than just nearby-word prediction.

Comment: Thank you gojomo for helping me again. Referring to your explanation above about dense embeddings, I get that the Word2Vec is not produce one-hot encoding but random dense embeddings as real-valued vector, am I right?

Comment: Word2Vec can be thought of as taking high-dimensional one-hot encodings as how the training examples are represented, then *learning* over training-time lower-dimensional dense embeddings (real-valued vectors with few if any zero dimensions). Those *start* random but the process of training forces them to be good at word-prediction, which then turns out to arrange them usefully for other purposes as well.